# proving the inequality $n \cdot a^{n-1} \cdot(b-a) < b^n - a^n < n \cdot b^{n-1} \cdot (b-a)$

Tags: calculus

let $b>a>0$ and $n>1$ I need to prove that:

$n \cdot a^{n-1} \cdot(b-a) < b^n - a^n < n \cdot b^{n-1} \cdot (b-a)$

I though of proving it using induction, or to build a function on where n is the variable but failed both times.

Comment: You can use the mean value theorem applied to $x\mapsto x^n$ and the fact that for $n>1$, $x\mapsto x^{n-1}$ is strictly increasing on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Try $b^n-a^n=(b-a)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+\ldots+a^{n-1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to prove this.

**Method 1:**

Using the fact that $\dfrac{b^n-a^n}{b-a}=b^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+a^{n-1}$, then
$$b^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+a^{n-1}>a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}+\cdots+a^{n-1}=na^{n-1}\\b^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+a^{n-1}<b^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+\cdots+b^{n-1}=nb^{n-1} \\na^{n-1}<\dfrac{b^n-a^n}{b-a}<nb^{n-1} \\ na^{n-1}(b-a)<b^n-a^n<nb^{n-1}(b-a)$$

**Method 2:**

Let $f(x)=x^n$, then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$.

By Mean Value Theorem, we know that $f'(a)<\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<f'(b)$.
$$na^{n-1}<\dfrac{b^n-a^n}{b-a}<nb^{n-1} \\ na^{n-1}(b-a)<b^n-a^n<nb^{n-1}(b-a)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x={b\over a}$, so that ${b^n-a^n\over b-a}=b^{n-1} {1-x^n\over 1-x}=b^{n-1}(1+x+...+x^{n-1})$.

As $0\leq x<1$, we deduce   $b^{n-1} \leq {b^n-a^n\over b-a} \leq n b^{n-1}$, and the result as $a<b$

Comment: There is a typo on second line

Answer (score 0):

I would try induction. Try using the fact that
\begin{align*}
(b^{n-1}-a^{n-1})(b-a) = (b^n-a^n) - ab^{n-1} + ba^{n-1}
\end{align*}

For the first step of the induction (i.e. n=2), this helps to obtain the result. I didn't try the general induction step, but probably you can use the same statement again.

Answer (score 0):

$b^{n}-a^{n}=(b-a)\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^{n-i}\cdot a^{i-1}$

Clearly $b^{n-1}>b^{n-i}\cdot a^{i-1}>a^{n-1}$. Therefore,

$na^{n-1}\cdot (b-a)<b^{n}-a^{n}<nb^{n-1}\cdot(b-a)$